How can I set the badge to the foreground in the corner of layout element (table card) in my android application with XML?
I want the badge to overlap other elements inside the layout, but now it looks like this
how it looks now
I have tried BringToFront(), setZ(), ContraintsLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, elevating, margin, padding, layout_alignParent, layout_below, but probably wrong and have no result.
My xml is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/table_minHeight">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBodyLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tableAlias_TablesPage"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="45" />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bookingBadge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_rounded_10"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/guestBill"
            android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_clock_black_24dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:tint="?attr/colorOnError" 
                android:scaleX="0.8" 
                android:scaleY="0.8"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bookingBadge_startTime_TablesPage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="13:20"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnError"
                android:paddingTop="1dp"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceLabelSmall"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

And C#:
public override void BindViews(View view, AsyncRecyclerViewHolder viewHolder)
    {
        using var set = CreateBindingSet<ObservableTable>(viewHolder);

        var card = view.FindViewById<MaterialCardView>(ResourceConstant.Id.card);
        set.Bind(card).For(CardBackgroundColorBinding.AttributeName).To(x => x.State).WithConversion<TableStateToBackgroundColorConverter>();
        set.Bind(card).For(x => x.BindClick()).To(x => x.ClickCommand);

        var tableAlias = view.FindViewById<TextView>(ResourceConstant.Id.tableAlias_TablesPage);
        set.Bind(tableAlias).To(x => x.Alias);
        set.Bind(tableAlias).For(TextViewTextColorBinding.AttributeName).To(x => x.State).WithConversion<TableStateToTextColorConverter>();

        var bookingBadge = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(ResourceConstant.Id.bookingBadge);
        set.Bind(bookingBadge).For(x => x.BindVisible()).To(x => x.BookingBadge!.Visibile);
        set.Bind(bookingBadge).For(ViewBackgroundTintBinding.AttributeName).To(x => x.BookingBadge!.Style).WithConversion<BadgeStyleToColorConverter>();

        var bookingBadgeStartTime = view.FindViewById<TextView>(ResourceConstant.Id.bookingBadge_startTime_TablesPage);
        set.Bind(bookingBadgeStartTime).To(x => x.BookingBadge!.StartTime);
    }

